# Examples of functions with properties

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

I'm looking for example of functions defined on $[0,+\infty)$ with the following properties:

1) continuous, twice differentiable

2) $f(0)=0$, $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=1/3$

3) $f^{\prime}>0$, $f^{\prime \prime}<0$

4) $f^{\prime}(0)=+\infty$, $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f^{\prime}(x)=0$

Do you have some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $f_1(x) = \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}+1}$, and $f_2(x) = \dfrac{2}{3\pi}\arctan(\sqrt{x})$ are both good examples.

Of course, there are infinitely many others out there.